# Math behind finding screen coordinates in a path tracer

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, rendering, pixel

I have been provided with a framework where a simple path tracer is implemented. What I am trying to do so far is understanding the whole code because I'll need to put my hands on it. Unfortunately I am arrived on a step where I don't actually get what's happening and since I am a newbie in the advanced graphics field I don't manage to "decrypt" this part. The developer is trying to get the coordinates of the screen corners as for comments. What I need to understand is the math behind it and therefore some of the variables that are used. Here is the code:

```
// setup virtual screen plane
vec3 E( 2, 8, -26 ), V( 0, 0, 1 );
static float r = 1.85f;
mat4 M = rotate( mat4( 1 ), r, vec3( 0, 1, 0 ) );
float d = 0.5f, ratio = SCRWIDTH / SCRHEIGHT, focal = 18.0f;
vec3 p1( E + V * focal + vec3( -d * ratio * focal,  d * focal, 0 ) ); // top-left screen corner
vec3 p2( E + V * focal + vec3(  d * ratio * focal,  d * focal, 0 ) ); // top-right screen corner
vec3 p3( E + V * focal + vec3( -d * ratio * focal, -d * focal, 0 ) ); // bottom-left screen corner
p1 = vec3( M * vec4( p1, 1.0f ) );
p2 = vec3( M * vec4( p2, 1.0f ) );
p3 = vec3( M * vec4( p3, 1.0f ) );
```

For example:

- what is the "d" variable and why both "d" and "focal" are fixed?
- is "focal" the focal length?
- What do you think are the "E" and "V" vectors?
- is the matrix "M" the CameraToWorldCoordinates matrix?

I need to understand every step of those formulas if possible, the variables, and the math used in those few lines of code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guesses:

`E`: eye position—position of the eye/camera in world space

`V`: view direction—the direction the camera is looking, in world coordinates

`d`: named constant for one half—corners are half the screen size away from the centre (where the camera is looking)

`focal`: distance of the image plane from the camera. Given its use in screen corner offsets, it also seems to be the height of the image plane in world coordinates.

`M`: I'd say this is the `WorldToCamera` matrix. It's used to transform a point which is based on `E`

How the points are computed:

1. Start at the camera: `E`
2. Move `focal` distance along the view direction, effectively moving to the centre of the image plane: `+ V * focal`
3. Add offsets on X & Y which will move half a screen distance: `+ vec3( ::: )`

   Given that `V` does not figure in the `vec3()` arguments (nor does any `up` or `right` vector), this seems to hard-code the idea that `V` is collinear with the Z axis.
4. Finally, the points are tranformed *as points* (as opposed to *directions,* since their homogenous coordinate is 1) by `M`.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's a bit more clear but I still need some explanation. First of all I don't get exactly what's inside the offset **+vect ( ::: )** .. Take the Y coordinate for example of p1. I need to move to the top since I am talking about the top-left corner. I am already in the center with the first part of the formula and I need an offset to the top which, in this case, is _d * focal_ which means half of the focal length. But the focal length, as you told me, is the distance of the image plane from the camera. So, why is it like that?

Comment: @Tarta Overall, this code doesn't look perfectly polished (notice my comment on semi-hard-coded `V`). It wouldn't surprise me if the second use of `focal` was actually a hidden bug.

Comment: mmm ok.. but let's say that we don't have the assumption of the focal length being equal to the height of the plane.  Is it right (about the X coordinate) to say that _focalLength * -0.5 * ratio_ gives me always the left border of the image plane? and again, if we don't have this weird assumption, how do we usually find the top border of the image plane instead of the formula used in this framework?

Comment: @Tarta Well, if `focal` is actually not the image plane size, you will have to use the image plane size instead of `focal` in the offset formulae. Side note: if you're going to work with code like this, you will need skills with 3D vectors, analytical geometry and linear algebra. You might want to find a book/tutorial/course on that.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Sorry for the late reply. I would like to ask you one last point if possible: I don't really get why it changes the point to homogeneous coordinates. What's the need in doing that? You say _the points are transformed as points (as opposed to directions, since their homogenous coordinate is 1)_ . Can you please explain me a bit more what do you mean?

Comment: @Tarta Homogenous coordinates (4D) allow translation to be expressed using a matrix. A 3x3 matrix can represent rotation, scaling, skew etc. of 3D points, but not translation. That's why 4D (homogenous) coordinates are used in graphics.`M` could, in principle, have a translation component.

Comment: Perfect, but the multiplication for that _M_ should mean also something else. It's not just a transformation to homogeneous coordinates because there is actually a rotation as well. That _M_ (as in code above) gives a rotation around the vector (0,1,0) of an angle _r = 1.85f_ if I understood correctly. Any practical reason for having this rotation of those points?

Comment: @Tarta You misunderstood me. `M` is a `mat4`, so presumably a 4x4 (homogenous) matrix. Therefore, to transform a vector (point or direction) by this matrix, it must be in homogenous coordinates too. That's why the 4th coordinate is added to the points in the multiplication. As for *why* `M` is the rotation which it is, I can't know - that's something to do with how it's used in the program.

Comment: Yes I got it, I was wondering why that rotation but thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sorry to bother you.. if I have those Vec3 p1, p2 and p3 and I do something like _(p2-p1)/ SCRWIDTH_ what do I actually find? the unit vector/direction, since I am dividing the vector (p2,p1) by its length? EDIT: no I don't according the debugging, because the resulting vector has not unit length.. therefore, what is it?

Comment: @Tarta That depends on the "unit" of `SCRWIDTH` (whether it's is in world coordinates or what). As long as `SCRWIDTH` is in the same units as `p2` and `p1`, that should be correct.

Comment: You are right.. indeed it's wrong because _SCRWIDTH_ is in pixel.. therefore I have no idea what I am finding, I will ask the owner probably.. thanks a lot! EDIT: maybe it's the size (dx and dy) of a pixel..